# Magento2 > how to remove some JS

Tags: magento2, javascript

I would like to remove these JS from my M2:

range.js
colorpicker.js
datepicker.js
tooltip.js
polyfill.js
decorate.js

Would someone know how to achieve that ?

Thanks.

Jack

Comment: Might need to disable those too: t️ranslate-inline.js, swatches-render.js, many thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can follow below blog to remove js

https://meetanshi.com/blog/remove-js-and-css-in-magento-2-using-layout-xml/